# Sum of a nested JSON value

Tags: javascript, json

I am attempting to get the sum of different status values from the following a set of JSON data returned from the server. My javascript works ok when the value is not nested but unfortunately the data I need is nested in each object.

From the code below I am trying to return the value of 2 in the alert (two objects with the value "Contacted" with a "Weighting" of 1).

Using "status.Status" and "status.Weighting" to get to the data does not work as expected it would. Help greatly appreciated on where I am going wrong

```
function showAlert() {
    var requests = 
   [ {          "contactNumber": "098989 258855",
                "createdDate": 1443861343172,
                "firstName": "Ralph",
                "notes": "First time buyer",
                "status": {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "Status": "Referred",
                    "Weighting": "2"
                },
                "surname": "Green",
                "title": "Mr",
                "updatedDate": 1443861343172
            },
     {          "contactNumber": "9999999999",
                "createdDate": 1444728401230,
                "firstName": "Sean",
                "notes": "Landlord",
                "status": {
                    "Id": 5,
                    "Status": "Application made",
                    "Weighting": "5"
                },
                "surname": "Jackson",
                "title": "Mr",
                "updatedDate": 1444728401230
            },
      {        "contactNumber": "9999999999",
                "createdDate": 1444728476347,
                "firstName": "Sam",
                "notes": "Remortgage",
                "status": {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "Status": "Contacted",
                     "Weighting": "1"
                },
                "surname": "Jenkins",
                "title": "Miss",
                "updatedDate": 1444728476347
             },
      {             "contactNumber": "9999999999",
                    "createdDate": 1444728476347,
                    "firstName": "Grace",
                    "notes": "Remortgage",
                    "status": {
                        "Id": 2,
                        "Status": "Contacted",
                        "Weighting": "1"
                    },
                    "surname": "Jones",
                    "title": "Miss",
                    "updatedDate": 1444728476347
                },
    ];
var sumByKey = function (array, keyField, keyValue, valueField) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++)
        if (array[i][keyField] == keyValue)
            sum += parseFloat(array[i][valueField])
    return sum;
}
alert(sumByKey(requests, "status.Status", "Contacted", "status.Weighting"));}
```

Comment: Can't use dot notation inside bracket notation

Comment: @JoshKG Yes he can, but it wont have the outcome he is looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this still making use of the dot notation. Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9wgj3xu/).

```
var sumByKey = function (array, keyField, keyValue, valueField) {
    var sum = 0;
    var keyFieldSplits = keyField.split(".");
    var valueFieldSplits = valueField.split(".");

    array.forEach(function(value){
        var start = value;
        keyFieldSplits.forEach(function(key){
            start = start[key];
        });

        if(start == keyValue) {
            start = value;
            valueFieldSplits.forEach(function(key){
                start = start[key];
            });
            sum += parseInt(start, 10);
        }
    });

    return sum;
}

alert(sumByKey(requests, "status.Status", "Contacted", "status.Weighting"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do something like this, splitting out the outer and inner object key values:

```
var sumByKey = function (array, outerKeyField, innerKeyField, keyValue, outerValueField, innerValueField) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++)
        if (array[i][outerKeyField][innerKeyField] == keyValue)
            sum += parseFloat(array[i][outerValueField][innerValueField])
    return sum;
}
```

And then pass in the properties appropriately:

```
alert(sumByKey(requests, "status", "Status", "Contacted", "status", "Weighting"));}
```

Alternatively, you'd have to add some string parsing to your function whenever keys with dot notation are detected, and change your logic accordingly.

Something like this ought to work:

```
var sumByKey = function(array, keyField, keyValue, valueField) {
  var sum = 0;
  var thisKey = "";
  var thisValue = "";
  for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (keyField.indexOf(".") > -1) {
      var keys = keyField.split(".");
      var obj = array[i][keys[0]];
      for (var j = 1, keyLen = keys.length; j < keyLen; j++) {
        obj = obj[keys[j]];
      }
      thisKey = obj;
    } else {
      thisKey = keyField;
    }
    if (thisKey == keyValue) {
      if (valueField.indexOf(".") > -1) {
        var vals = valueField.split(".");
        obj = array[i][vals[0]];
        for (var j = 1, valLen = vals.length; j < valLen; j++) {
          obj = obj[vals[j]];
        }
        thisValue = obj;
      } else {
        thisValue = array[i][valueField];
      }
      sum += parseFloat(thisValue)
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

```js
var example = [{
  "status": {
    "status": "contacted",
    "weight": 1
  }
}, {
  "status": {
    "status": "contacted",
    "weight": 1
  }
}, {
  "status": {
    "status": "ignored",
    "weight": 1
  }
}];

var sumByKey = function(array, keyField, keyValue, valueField) {
  var sum = 0;
  var thisKey = "";
  var thisValue = "";
  for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (keyField.indexOf(".") > -1) {
      var keys = keyField.split(".");
      var obj = array[i][keys[0]];
      for (var j = 1, keyLen = keys.length; j < keyLen; j++) {
        obj = obj[keys[j]];
      }
      thisKey = obj;
    } else {
      thisKey = keyField;
    }
    if (thisKey == keyValue) {
      if (valueField.indexOf(".") > -1) {
        var vals = valueField.split(".");
        obj = array[i][vals[0]];
        for (var j = 1, valLen = vals.length; j < valLen; j++) {
          obj = obj[vals[j]];
        }
        thisValue = obj;
      } else {
        thisValue = array[i][valueField];
      }
      sum += parseFloat(thisValue)
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
alert(sumByKey(example, "status.status", "contacted", "status.weight"));
```

Comment: That doesn't feel like a very arbitrary solution. What if he has more then one level deep keys like `a.b.c.d`?

Comment: @Oleander yeah, I thought about that right after I posted. It's since been edited with a basic example of parsing a string for dot notation. EDIT: Ah, and I see you've beaten me to the punch with your own answer!